# Possible bug in 7zip - empty folders extract as empty files

Tags: compression, zip, archiving, 7-zip, user-folders

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
Main
|
|--empty_folder
|
|--folder
   |
   |--example.txt
```

I'm zipping it using the .NET ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory method (but I doubt this has anything to do with the problem)

When I extract the archive using Windows Explorer the empty folder shows as expected. However if I extract the archive using 7zip the empty folder shows as a file! Has anyone else experienced this and if so is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Works as expected here. Which version of 7-zip?  Which version of Windows? How exactly are you using 7-zip to extract it?  can you provide a link to an example Zip file you've made that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I came to the same error using ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I just had the same problem and managed to solve it very simply.

This seems to be a problem with a specific version of 7-Zip. Updating 7-Zip to version 16.04 solves the problem, and no longer created empty files instead of empty folders.